# Update div with jquery ajax update

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I'm trying to update the div tag of my view page with ajax call.

The ajax call is made from  my index view of my post controller
and I call the create view of my comment controller.

In my view post,  I have the following

```
<div id="comment<?php echo $this->comment_row; ?>"> </div>
```

which give me  id=comment1,  id=comment2,  ....

with my jquery script I want to update the div with the result of the call to the create view of the comment controller

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){                     
      $(function(){
         $("#sb").click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('comment/create'); ?>",
               update: "'#comment'.$this->comment_row"

           });
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

When I trying this, I got no error  but the div is not updated.

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){                     
      $(function(){
         $("#sb").click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('comment/create'); ?>",
               success: function(data) {
                    $("#comment<?php echo $this->comment_row;?>").html(data);
               }

           });
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `success` instead of `update`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('comment/create'); ?>",
  success: function(data) {
    $(this).html(data);
   }
});
```

Also make sure that your controller is returning the `data` to update.

Comment: No changes.  Maybe the controller is not returning the data